# Object reference not set to an instance of an object #5

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

```
sUsername.Trim();
sPassword.Trim();
string ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbnameConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
```

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any ideas? I don't understand the error.

Comment: Well, I do understand it, but you miss line references. Where does the error occur?

Comment: WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbnameConnectionString"]  returned null

Comment: Two upvotes for this question?  Seriously?

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: Will someone please close this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net?

Answer (score 9):

Well, you haven't shown which line it occurs on. It suggests that one of these occurred:

- `sUsername` was null
- `sPassword` was null
- `WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbnameConnectionString"]` returned null

Btw, calling `Trim()` as a statement on its own like that is pointless. Strings are immutable - `Trim()` *returns* the trimmed version. You want something like:

```
sUsername = sUsername.Trim();
sPassword = sPassword.Trim();
```

... but only after checking whether they're null or not.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I do understand it, but you miss line references. Where does the error occur?

```
Line 30:         sUsername.Trim();
Line 31:         sPassword.Trim();
Line 32:         string ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbnameConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
Line 33:         SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
Line 34:         try
```

if I assume that sPassword exists - and sUsername...
...then does the ConnectionString "dbNameConnectionString" exist in the web.config? If not- that is null, and the ".ConnectionString" naturally throws that error.

Comment: Ah yes, I had forgotten to edit the web.config - working now, thanks.

Comment: mark as answer if this fixed it!  I know this is an old post but still

Answer (score 1):

Line 30 and 31 don't do anything:

```
sUsername = sUsername.Trim();
sPassword= sPassword.Trim();
```

Post where the error occurs

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of any one of the variable is NULL. You can check the value of `sUserName` and `sPassword` variables during debugging (runtime).

Answer (score 0):

This just means that you're trying to access a member of a null reference; i.e. one of the variables here is `null`. Without knowing the line number it's difficult to say which, but I'd guess at either `sUsername` or `sPassword`.